# Game Center Support

Tags: xcode, ios5, app-store-connect, game-center

I want to add game center leaderboards to my app.

In some youtube videos and other tut's i've seen that you need to enter a category to the leaderboard in itunes connect. Where do I do that, because i don't get asked to do so.

Or could you tell me how to add game center anyways? what i did now is:

```
   GKScore *myScoreValue = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"moveItQuickLeaderbord"];


    myScoreValue.value = Punkte;
    [myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error]);



        } else {
            NSLog(@"Score Submitted");

        }

    }];
```

and in the view did load:

```
 [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if (error ==nil) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Fail");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error]);

    }

}];
```

when i upload my score i always get the score submitted message but if i look at the leaderboard it does not contain any values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enrolled in the iOS Developer program, you should have access to the iTunes Connect website. There, you need to setup an App ID and activate Game Center. After that you can create a leaderboard and enter an unique id for in as well as other properties.

Comment: yes have enrolled in the ios develper program and i have done all that stuff. but which name do o have to enter here: initWithCategory:@"??"  ?

Comment: The string in initWithCategory: should be the Leaderboard ID from iTunesConnect.

Comment: okay, thank you. But somehow it's still not working. is it a problem to set up the app ID after i have created the app in itunes connect?

Comment: By "not working" do you mean, that the scores do not show in GameCenter Sandbox mode? When I develop apps that support Game Center, the scores don't show up on the leaderboard. However, once I release the app, the leaderboards work. I don't know if that is normal.